# Django urls are fine in development, but are being cut in production

Tags: python, mysql, django, url

I created a Django application that generates urls for blog posts based in the post title.

In development environment the urls are ok, being created from the whole title, but in production the urls are being cut, and limited to only a few characters.

As Django files are exactly the same in both environments, I suspect it could be something related or with the server, or with the database (MySQL used in production ans SQLite in development).

**Example:**

**Article Title:**
*"What was the one thing you wish you knew before starting a company?"*

**url in development:**
*mydomain.com/what-was-the-one-thing-you-wish-you-knew-before-starting-a-company*

**url in production:**
*mydomain.com/what-was-the-one-thing-you-wis*

This is the code related to create and save the blog post objects:

**MODELS:**

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Title')
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250)
```

**VIEWS:**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.slug = slugify(form_data.title)
            slug = form_data.slug
            # If slug is already taken, add a random number at the end of it
            try:
                Pergunta.objects.get(slug=slug)
                form_data.slug = slug + str(randint(0,100))
            except:
                pass

            form_data.save()
            form.save_m2m()
```

**URLS:**

```
    url(r'^blogpost/(?P<slug>.*)$', views.blogpost, name='blogpost'),
```

**MYSQL Table Columns:**

```
| id          | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |     auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| autor_id    | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                    | select,insert,update,references |         |
| title      | varchar(300) | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                    | select,insert,update,references |         |
| slug        | varchar(50)  | utf8_general_ci | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                    | select,insert,update,references |         |
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some code, like maybe from the model?

Comment: please show your views, template and model

Comment: What's your url definition? How do you call the urls? Please post those code as well.

Comment: Which collation is the `slug` column using in your database? Open up a shell using `python manage.py dbshell` and run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM <table>`. By default the tablename is `<app_name>_<model_name>`.

Comment: Did you manually alter the size of the slug column in MySQL, or make a change to the model without a migration? Your model says it should have a length of 250, but in the table it's only 50.

Comment: You got it! 
My apps had no initial migrations, so the changes I made in models were not being applied. I did a `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` for each app and then `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`
Thanks a lot!